# Any BLE lib (most usual programming languages possible)

Tags: windows, bluetooth, uwp, libraries, desktop

I have the task to write a Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) tool that communicates with a BLE able device (using Windows!).
There are some UWP libs which I cannot use because I don't know how to develop with UWP.

I had a look at Java, C++ (and Qt) and C# libs but there aren't any available for windows desktop application.

Do you have any idea what to do?

Err, no, I don't have enough time to learn UWP.

Best regards

Comment: is this useful https://github.com/urish/win-ble-cpp or this https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/samples/blegatt and this https://developer.mbed.org/questions/3285/Are-there-any-BLE-examples-for-Windows-A/

Comment: and this https://www.bluetooth.com/develop-with-bluetooth/developer-resources-tools/developer-kits/app-acc-2 I just wrote BLE for Windows in google

Comment: actually it is not possible to use these for developing a desktop app. :(